# React JS - app not filling the entire page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I am using React JS.
I have 3 components:

1. nav
2. div
3. section

Folders:

- (Folder: Navbar.js, Navbar.scss)
- (Folder: MyDivSection.js, MyDivSection.scss)
- (Folder: MySection.js, MySection.scss)
- App.js   (where all of the above components are called)
- index.js ( ReactDOM.render(, document.getElementById('root')); )

Here is the layout of my page:
[image: page layout]

There is a white/empty area at the bottom of the page, that I want to get rid of using sass/css ?

How to achieve that ?

**Note:** The white/empty area appears only in 768px, 480px and 1200px resolutions

Comment: Do you want a background? Do you want `nav`, `div` and/or 'section' to expand? What is your intended output? You have to be more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the problem, Then you would have menu=nav , Content=div and section=footer.

Then the height of the menu should be fixed where the content and footer could be in %. this is the problem you are getting.

You need to increase the content so that it fills the white secion

Here is how I would do it.

```css
.app{
display:inline-block;
width: 98vw;
height:95vh;
}

.app> div{
  width:100%;

}

.app .nav{
background:red;
height:30px;
}

.app .content{
background:blue;
height:75%;
}

.app .footer{
background:green;
height:20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
<div class="nav">nav</div>
<div class="content">div</div>
<div class="footer">section</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and read about `flexbox` in general but [here're few handy examples of layouts](https://medium.com/@merveyuksek/webpage-layout-examples-with-flexbox-88287f010a08) that might help you